# How to get array length in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my script tag

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: [],    
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.paginate_total = this.blogs.length / this.paginate; 
  },   
};
</script>
```

these the response I get in my console

```
{
   
    "blogs": [
   
        {
            "_id": "63243272c988e721db51de9c",
            
        },
        {
            "_id": "63243cb8a8189f8080411e65",        
        },
      
    ]
}
```

error i get in my console

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Please what I'm I doing wrong

Comment: I tried to reproduce your erro but I didn't found the error in the code that you posted. Probably the problem is in the way that ypu populate blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the object array length in mounted or created lifecycles so I just used watch property to get the object length

```
watch: {
   blogs(blogs) {
      this.paginate_total = blogs.length / this.paginate;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this line in mounted instead of created

```
this.paginate_total = this.blogs.length / this.paginate;
```

because this blog is not available in created yet that's why it is undefined.

Comment: I though that too but I did a code snippet here and works well. The documentation says that in created hook the reactive data is setted up so I don't think is that. Here's [my code](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNo9UEtqxTAMvIrQqoXEodvwWug5qi6cRPk84g+20hZC7l7H+YDBGs14rNGKn96rn4Wxxkdsw+Tlgyz/eRcEOu71MstKFqDTol9ecwkQWJZg4UQAzeyGWH8R9s4RFoSNDoTfxcXPbAcZ6/LtaGz7tWW2DayFu9tZximqQw7vB8rmZy8/JJvOo7qnTUDY+DkZJQSwrod4y7KbwgIns+cqjfbqGZ1NmfO3dBKRsL5CEaal7JhwFPGxrqrYt/umnlG5MFSpUmGxMhlWHE3ZBPcbOSRjwmtM3P4Bq9J3Cw==)

Comment: Solved it using watch property  thank for your time

Answer (score 0):

For row counts (as for table pagination etc.) i would use a computed property like:

```js
computed: {
  paginate_total() {
      return this.blogs.length;
  },
}
```